# File explorer tool in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a C# project using windows forms. I need to let the user enter the location of a text file, so they will need some way to browse files and folders i.e. a button that opens a file explorer. What tool (in the toolbox) would this be in Visual Studio 2010? I tried DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher but that just adds something to the bottom like this:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear, you need to select a folder or do you need to choose a file from the file system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not that easy. You want the file open dialog. You would have to add a button, then in the handler for the button open the dialog.

```
OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
if(fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
// do something here with fdlg.FileName ;
}
```

[source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/BrowseorOpenaFile12012005010624AM/BrowseorOpenaFile.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's the Dialogs section.  Look for the OpenFileDialog or one of the others (according to your needs)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OpenFileDialog component as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61097ykx.aspx